# Why this List[String] to dataframe casues NullPointerException in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following codesnippet is causing NullPointerException. I am not sure, if this exception is happening on some rows or always as the dataframe is huge and not able to pin point the row.

```
def removeUnwantedLetters(str: String): String = {
    str.split("\\W+").filter(word => (word.matches("[a-z]+") && (word.length > 1))).mkString(" ")
}

val myudf = spark.udf.register("learningUDF", (f1: String, f2: String) => {
    if(f1 != null && f2 != null) {
        val preproList = List(removeUnwantedLetters(f2.toLowerCase));

        if(preproList > 0) {
            val key_items = preproList.toDF("Description")
        }
    }

    (1, 1)
})



mydataframe.withColumn("pv", myudf($"f1", $"f2")).show
```

The entire code is huge, so sorry for not pasting the entire code here, tried my best to minimize the failing code here. Following is the exception that I am getting on the actual code:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 274.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 274.0 (TID 23387, 10.62.145.186, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) => struct<_1:int,_2:double>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.ScalaUDF$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_26$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:100)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:82)
    ... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
  ... 66 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) => struct<_1:int,_2:double>)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.ScalaUDF$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_26$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:100)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:82)
  ... 22 more
```

By trial and error I have found out that this line `val key_items = preproList.toDF("Description")` is causing the NPE. Because if I change it simply to `val key_items = preproList`, it works fine.

```
Can anyone please let me know when would `val key_items = preproList.toDF("Description")` give a `NullPointerException`.
```

### Update

It seems like we cannot create a dataframe inside a UDF. Because I tried replacing `val key_items = preproList.toDF("Description")` with `val key_items = List(1,2,3,4).toDF("VL")`. And to my surprise, it failed with the same exception.

Is it not possible to create a temporary dataframe inside a UDF?

### Update 2

I am trying to create a temporary dataframe to use [JohnSnowLabs](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp) Norvig Spell correction model using its pipeline as follows:

```
val nlpPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("Description").setOutputCol("document"),
  new Tokenizer().setInputCols("document").setOutputCol("tokens"),
  norvigspell.setInputCols("tokens").setOutputCol("Description_corrected"),
  new Finisher().setInputCols("Description_corrected")
))

val dbDF = preproList.toDF("Description")

val spellcorrectedDF = dbDF.transform(dbDF=> nlpPipeline.fit(dbDF).transform(dbDF))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort answer is: **No, you can't create a `DataFrame` (or `Dataset`) inside a UDF**. UDFs operate on individual row values and so are required to return simple values that can be stored in a new column, think of them as *Calculated Columns*. **If you could create a `DataFrame` inside a UDF, it will only have one row, and you would be creating many of them, one per row of the parent `DataFrame`**.

Now, from your code is difficult to tell what you want to do, in a way I see you are attempting some sort of character clean up, storing it in a `key_items` value (as a DataFrame) and never using it... to end up returning a constant `(1, 1)` pair regardless of the previous computation... The fact that **your UDF takes 2 parameters and you only use one** is puzzling to me too.

I will guess that you want to *compute the description* based on the value of one given column (you are only using one) so something like the following will get you something similar:

```
def removeUnwantedLetters(str: String): String = {
    str.split("\\W+").filter(word => (word.matches("[a-z]+") && (word.length > 1))).mkString(" ")
}

val myudf = spark.udf.register("learningUDF", (f1: String) => {
    if(f1 != null) {
        removeUnwantedLetters(f2.toLowerCase)
    } else ""
})

// This seems to be the DataFrame you are looking for
val descriptionDF = mydataframe
  .withColumn("Description", myudf($"f2"))
  .select("Description")
```

With the previous, Spark can create the column `Description` out of invoking your UDF over all the values of the DataFrame. Then, by using `.select("Description")` you are creating a new DataFrame that only has the `Description` column.

Comment: I am trying to create the dataframe just to use the JohnSnowLabs NorvigSpell correction `pipeline`. Because it is expecting a dataframe. Updating my question description with this extra information which explains the need for creating a dataframe. Please suggest any alternative approach. Thank you for taking time to answer my query.

Comment: I have updated the description under "Update2" section. Please suggest anything which I can do to use the JohnSnowLabs spell correction.

Comment: @user3243499 I can't really tell how to use the correction model you are talking about, that may need a different question. What I can say is that you are misunderstanding the usage of an `UDF`, I edited my answer as an attempt to clarify it.

Comment: But this sample code works where I do create a dataframe inside a UDF:
`val upperUDF = spark.udf.register("upperUDF", (input: String) => {
          val xy = List(1,2,3,4,5).toDF("nums")
          input.toUpperCase
     });`

`val dst = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text");`
`dst.withColumn("upper", upperUDF('text)).show;`